# iOS 13 system access request callbacks change?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios13

iOS 13 seems to have changed the way system access requests call back to your app.  In iOS 12 and earlier, my ViewController would refresh upon a choice by the user.  Now it sits idle after the user choice.  The VC is presented only one time, modally, fullscreen, so it's not seemingly related to these sheet/page form changes in iOS13, but curious if anyone else has seen this alert behavior change, has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up checking for iOS 13 and `PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` and could somewhat replicate the legacy behavior of the system call back.